# Derivative of complex function series at 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(z-1)^n}{n\cdot2^n\cdot(n+2)^2}, \; z\in \mathbb{C}$ $$\text{Show that } f^{(4)}(1)=\dfrac{1}{96}$$

$\underline{\text{My Solution:}}$

I have calculated fourth derivative of the series as:

$$f^{(4)}(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\dfrac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{2^n\cdot(n+2)^2}(z-1)^{n-4}$$

However,

$$f^{(4)}(1)=0$$

Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $(z-1)^{4-4}=1$. The first term of the sum is nonzero:$\frac{(4-1)(4-2)(4-3)}{2^4\cdot(4+2)^2}=\frac{1}{96}$

Comment: The value will be the coefficient of $(z-1)^4$ times $4!$ which isn’t zero.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help